# making source in subfolder question

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have makefile that compiles all *.c files in subfolder:

```
objects := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
cobj: $(objects)
$(objects): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

I am having trouble trying to do the same from parent folder. Lets say my .c files are in the folder 'csrc'

```
objects := $(addprefix, csrc/, $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c)))
cobj: $(objects)
$(objects): csrc/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

i always see "nothing to do for cobj... Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want `foo.o` to go into the parent directory or `csrc/`?

Comment: stay in csrc/, probably not so important.... thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern rule `csrc/%.o: %.c` translates e.g. `csrc/foo.o` into `foo.c`, not `csrc/foo.c`.  Presumably, that is not what you want.

Why not just `%.o: %.c`?

Answer (score 1):

What Oli Charlesworth said is correct, but there's another mistake. The wildcard function only checks the current directory. As it is now, `$(objects)` will be empty (I assume there are no source files in the current, parent directory). You will have to specify the path: `$(wildcard csrc/*.c)`

Comment: $(wildcard csrc/*.c) - that's the ticket. Thank you.

Comment: any idea what the deal is with 'wildcard' and spaces in folder names? $(wildcard csrc/*.c) works but $(wildcard csrc 1.0/*.c) doesn't. Neither does $(wildcard csrc\ 1.0/*.c), or $(wildcard "csrc 1.0"/*.c), or other usual tricks to contain whitespace in folder name...

Comment: @user270398: In general, make interprets a space as a separator, so in this case the wildcard function sees this as the two independent patterns `csrc` and `1.0/*.c`, which it tries to match separately, each obviously returning no matches. I might have guessed escaping the space would have been possible, but apparently not. One of the (many) reasons why spaces in folder and file names are a bad idea.